# Most helpful NDepend CQL queries

Tags: ndepend, cql

A client I work for has begun using NDepend as a replacement for FXCop, and the "architect" has compiled a list of practically unusable CQL queries, which I gather he has taken from advice from the NDepend website.

An example of what "I think" is an unhelpful query

```
WARN IF Count > 0 IN 
SELECT METHODS WHERE PercentageComment < 20 
AND NbLinesOfCode > 10
```

ie: must have at least 2 lines of comment for each 10 lines of code

So what I trying to gather is a **useful** set of queries that we can use as developers.

*Please only provide a **single** query per response (with description) so that it can be voted accordingly*.
*Please only provide a single query **per response** (with description) so that it can be voted accordingly*.

Comment: If your architect is concentrating on the percentage number of comments, you have a bigger problem than the best CQL queries!

Comment: It depends. Your product, existing code base, people in your team will all affect the rules that are important to you. I would personally remove the rule on comments.

Answer (score 4):

Xian, now that CQLinq (Code Rule over LINQ Query) is released, dozens of new default rules are available and most existing ones have been enhanced.

Here are ten of my preferred ones:

- [Avoid namespaces dependency cycles](http://www.ndepend.com/DefaultRules/webframe.html?Q_Avoid_namespaces_dependency_cycles.html)
- [UI layer shouldn't use directly DB types](http://www.ndepend.com/DefaultRules/webframe.html?Q_UI_layer_shouldn%27t_use_directly_DB_types.html)
- [Types with disposable instance fields must be disposable](http://www.ndepend.com/DefaultRules/webframe.html?Q_Types_with_disposable_instance_fields_must_be_disposable.html)
- [Types that used to be 100% covered by test but not anymore](http://www.ndepend.com/DefaultRules/webframe.html?Q_Types_that_used_to_be_100__covered_but_not_anymore.html)
- [Avoid transforming an immutable type into a mutable one](http://www.ndepend.com/DefaultRules/webframe.html?Q_Avoid_transforming_an_immutable_type_into_a_mutable_one.html)
- [Avoid making complex methods even more complex](http://www.ndepend.com/DefaultRules/webframe.html?Q_Avoid_making_complex_methods_even_more_complex_%28Source_CC%29.html)
- [API Breaking Changes: Types](http://www.ndepend.com/DefaultRules/webframe.html?Q_API_Breaking_Changes__Types.html)
- [Potentially dead Methods](http://www.ndepend.com/DefaultRules/webframe.html?Q_Potentially_dead_Methods.html)
- [Namespace name should correspond to file location](http://www.ndepend.com/DefaultRules/webframe.html?Q_Namespace_name_should_correspond_to_file_location.html)
- [Methods should be declared static if possible](http://www.ndepend.com/DefaultRules/webframe.html?Q_Methods_should_be_declared_static_if_possible.html)

Comment: Hi Patrick.. thanks for the response.. Would you possibly be able to break each of these rules into individual answers so they can be voted independently?